# Mongoose refuses to populate hasMany relationship

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I'm trying to make a very simple thing : Populate hasMany documents (links) from an document (product)

According to Mongoose [documentation about population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

My Product model is like :

```
const modelSchema = schema({ // const schema = mongoose.Schema
  [...]
  _links: [{
    type: schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Link'
  }]
})
const Product = mongoose.model('Product', modelSchema)
```

and my Link model :

```
const modelSchema = schema({
  [...]
  _product: {
    type: schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Product'
  }
})
const Link = mongoose.model('Link', modelSchema)
```

I can save in both sides, find any record, populate product from Link.find().populate('_product')

but, impossible to populate links from a product :

```
Product
    .find()
    .populate('_links')
    .exec(...)
-> {
    _links: []
   }
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

I've also notice that in the documentation, _id are forced to be Number, is it a part of the solution ?

Comment: How do you save models? Are the db content that one you want? Which version of mongoose you are using?

Comment: I'm using Link.create(obj) where obj has { _product: product_id }. Mongoose  4.5.8.